# Executing java MySQL stored procedure from PHP

Tags: java, php, mysql, apache, java-stored-procedures

I have a PHP page that processes incoming information, it takes the parameters and constructs a command to execute a Java class on the server using `shell_exec()`.

The Java class takes the parameter and calls a stored procedure in MySQL and returns the required results. i have tested my Java class independently from the terminal and it is working perfectly.

My problem is that when I execute the Java class from PHP it runs until the line where I am defining the stored procedure calls and it stops there and returns `NULL`!

```
cSt = conn.prepareCall("{CALL prcName(?,?,?,?)}");
```

The are no exceptions while executing since the above line is in a `try catch` and no message from `catch` is printed.

The program just runs until this line and returns `NULL`!

Here is the PHP page:

```
<?php     
    $name= $_POST['name'];
    $contact= $_POST['contact'];

    $response =  shell_exec("java ClassName".$name." ".$contact);

    echo $response;
?>
```

Java class (part):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //connection to database
        int returnValue = methodName(args[0], args[1]);
        System.out.print(String.valueOf(returnValue));
        //close connection to db
}
public static int methodName(String name,String contact){
        int result = 5; 
        try {
            cSt = conn.prepareCall("{CALL prcName(?,?,?)}");
            cst.CallableStament().setString("name",name);
            cst.CallableStament().setString("contact",contact);
            cst.CallableStament().registerOutParameter("rtn", java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            cst.CallableStament().execute();

            result = cst.CallableStament().getInt("rtn");           
        } catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        return result;
    }
```

UPDATE: 
i have narrowed down from where the problem was and finally found that while specifiying the driver by `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` 
i get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at Classname.Connect(classname.java:29)
    at classname.
```

UPDATE 2:
  to be able to use the driver i added the CLASSPATH in `/etc/profile/`
  however i noticed that the change is only for login users. But apache is using            the user "www-data" while running the `shell_exec()` and i cant figure a way to assign the classpath to that user.

Comment: add `e.printStacktrace()` to get the details of the error.

Comment: show more code T. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/calling-mysql-stored-procedures-from-jdbc/

Comment: There are no errors! the java program just stop at that line when i call it using `shell_exec()`. i used `system.out.print()` in the method calling the stored procedure to know where exactly stops working.

Comment: could you post the relevant code

Comment: added the code close to what i have!

Comment: could you also post the procedure `prcName`?

Comment: i don't think its from the procedure since i tested in in workbench and also from terminal and is giving expected result!

Comment: Why not just call the stored procedure from php? That will be quicker then starting a Java program first. For the mysql driver: Search StackOverflow.

Comment: i;m calling from java since there are other processing to be done after words that cannot be done on php. I think i found the error, the classpath for the driver is in my user home directly but while calling shell_exec() i found out that "www-data" user is used!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the classpath to the executed command, or else set CLASSPATH before you run the PHP script.

```
$response =  shell_exec("java -classpath mysql.jar ClassName".$name." ".$contact);
```

> java -h

```
-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives, # : separated list on Linux
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
```

Oh, by the way, executing a shell command based on the contents of a web POST is super insecure. Someone could just POST `; rm -f /` to wipe out your system, or other things to hack you.

Comment: thanks for the info. but is there any other way to execute those java classes from php which shell command?